# Why can't I use type-checked variable in first condition as type-casted variable in second condition?

Tags: java, class, object, casting, type-conversion

```
class A
{
    boolean foo() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Why is the following giving syntax error?
*method is undefined for type*

```
if(a instanceOf A && a.foo()) {
.....
}
```

This works fine-

```
if(a instanceOf A && ((A)a).foo()) {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To a human it's clear that `a` is of type `A` because of the `instanceof` check. The compiler doesn't work like that though and therefore you still need to cast `a` to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, the [`instanceof` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) simply returned `true` or `false` and had no effect on the types of its operands.

[As of Java 14, `instanceof` supports pattern matching](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305) (or see spec preview [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/preview/specs/patterns-instanceof-jls.html)). You are able to declare a new variable inline that will be of the `instanceof`'s target type if and only if the check was successful.

For example, your code would look like

```
if(a instanceof A actual && actual.foo()) {
    // ...
}
```